# Allow both Subversion based (passwd file) and Windows domain authentication

Tags: windows, svn, apache

I have Subversion currently set up on Windows to authenticate against our domain controller via Apache. Is it possible to allow authentication against both the domain controller and the Subversion passwd file?

To accomplish this, would I have to have Apache for Windows authentication and also have svnserve run as a service and have that check against the passwd file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to apply mixed authentication. You can use the HTTP protocol via Apache for Windows authentication and use the SVN protocol via `svnserve` to authenticate against the `passwd` file.

You can use Stefan's solution, but that does not prevent you from clearly separating different classes of users.

Comment: Chosen for separation of user classes

Comment: +1. Also just want to record here that the passwd method of authentication transmits the passwords as cleartext over the network - so if that bothers your sensibilities, look into using other more secure methods like ssh as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell Apache to provide basic authentication (using the `passwd` file) if the authentication against the domain controller fails.

Set the line

```
SSPIOfferBasic On
```

in your `<Location>` block in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: I already have SSPIOfferBasic on so that TortoiseSVN can authenticate against the Domain Controller (I read that without it, TortoiseSVN wont be able to authenticate).  If I understand you correctly, I just have to specify the passwd file for the <Location> block, correct?